# Remove words starting with two slashes in a string

Tags: php

How could I remove words that start with two slashes from my string?

```
$string = 'Hello bla bla //NAME';
```

In my echo call, I want to remove **//NAME** but the value "NAME" might change so it should only validate on the two slashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Using `preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
//Regular expression
$re = "/(\/\/[^\s]*\s)/"; 

//String (sample)
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, //consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus augue nunc, maximus eget ligula ac, tristique pulvinar turpis. Donec sit amet rhoncus risus, ac facilisis tortor. Vivamus id ante imperdiet, mattis enim non, luctus nulla. Cras tempor mi eget malesuada condimentum. Ut non est //pharetra, pulvinar dui nec, ultricies quam. Duis finibus diam eros, in tempor velit dignissim et. Ut eget varius ex, id posuere risus. Nam fermentum, diam nec ornare pretium, nulla nunc fermentum eros, eu efficitur ipsum orci eget velit. Integer et sem orci. Nunc hendrerit orci et pulvinar lobortis. Nam cursus malesuada malesuada. In vitae turpis nunc. //Ut eleifend erat magna, ut //condimentum elit ullamcorper quis."; 

//Preg_replace in the string with the regex, replacing with ""
$str_replaced = preg_replace($re, "", $str);

//Output
echo $str_replaced;
```

Input:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, //consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus augue nunc, maximus eget ligula ac, tristique pulvinar turpis. Donec sit amet rhoncus risus, ac facilisis tortor. Vivamus id ante imperdiet, mattis enim non, luctus nulla. Cras tempor mi eget malesuada condimentum. Ut non est //pharetra, pulvinar dui nec, ultricies quam. Duis finibus diam eros, in tempor velit dignissim et. Ut eget varius ex, id posuere risus. Nam fermentum, diam nec ornare pretium, nulla nunc fermentum eros, eu efficitur ipsum orci eget velit. Integer et sem orci. Nunc hendrerit orci et pulvinar lobortis. Nam cursus malesuada malesuada. In vitae turpis nunc. //Ut eleifend erat magna, ut //condimentum elit ullamcorper quis.

Output:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing elit. Vivamus augue nunc, maximus eget ligula ac, tristique pulvinar turpis. Donec sit amet rhoncus risus, ac facilisis tortor. Vivamus id ante imperdiet, mattis enim non, luctus nulla. Cras tempor mi eget malesuada condimentum. Ut non est pulvinar dui nec, ultricies quam. Duis finibus diam eros, in tempor velit dignissim et. Ut eget varius ex, id posuere risus. Nam fermentum, diam nec ornare pretium, nulla nunc fermentum eros, eu efficitur ipsum orci eget velit. Integer et sem orci. Nunc hendrerit orci et pulvinar lobortis. Nam cursus malesuada malesuada. In vitae turpis nunc. eleifend erat magna, ut elit ullamcorper quis.

---

Explaining the regular expression:

```
/(\/\/[^\s]*\s)/
```

1. `/` start of regex
2. `(` start of capturing group
3. `\/` matches "/" literally
4. `\/` matches "/" literally
5. `[^\s]*` any character except "\s" (whitespace) between zero and unlimited times
6. `\s` any whitespace character
7. `)` end of capturing group
8. `/` end of regex

Comment: One of the greatest answers I've ever seen.

Comment: @mitkosoft: Thank you! Madsen: My pleasure.